# Não consigo listar os valores exclusivos do dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe com 1 milhão de linhas, sei que para listar o valores únicos seria `df['Col'].unique()`, mas não consigo ver todos, pois esse metodo mostra somente as primeiras linhas e as ultimas, deixando oculto as linhas do meio do dataframe. Como poderia ver todos esses valores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocultar o meio dos dataframes é uma configuração padrão do Pandas, já que na maioria das vezes não faz sentido ficar vendo datas "lá no meio" - vendo o início e o final dá pra ter uma ideia de como o frame está.  Se a pessoa quiser ver um conjunto de linhas específicas, seleciona aquelas linhas com a notação de índices.

Os resultados finais dicilmente vão ser consumidos na própria tela - então, ao fim de um cálculo, o dataframe é gravado para um arquivo em CSV/Excel/Banco de dados onde os dados serão consumidos.

Bom, tudo isso pra explicar por que o Pandas faz isso por padrão. Claro que muitas vezs podemos querer ver todos os dados na tela, e em alguns casos, "consumir" os dados direto dali -

A configuração de quantas linhas são mostradas no Pandas fica no atributo `pd.options.display.max_rows` - é só aumentar esse número que a quantidade de linahs exibidas de um datframe sem o recorte muda.

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000000
```

iria exibir mesmo seu dataframe original, inteiro. (Claro que você levaria uma meia hora só pra rolar ele pra baixo)