# Compressão e Leitura de arquivo CSV com grande escala de linhas x colunas via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, big-data, mineração-de-textos

Estou empacado procurando uma forma precisa e intuitiva em realizar a leitura de um arquivo de 70.000KB formado pela concatenação de diversos arquivos sendo eles com tamanhos variados. Inicialmente de posse de diversos arquivos no formato '.txt' converti cada um deles utilizando um algorítmo que realizei para eliminar a existência de valores 0 e para cada um dos espaços encontrados ('\t') separei os valores do dataset com vírgula, e logo após ter convertido todos os CSV's concatenei todos em um único arquivo com pandas:

```py
inn="C:\\Documents\\experimento"    
out="C:\\Documents\\experimento\\full_dataset.csv"

    os.chdir(inn)
    FullCsv = gb.glob('*.csv')
    dfList=list()
    for simpleCsv in FullCsv:
        print(simpleCsv)
        df=pd.read_csv(simpleCsv,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatDf.to_csv(out,index=None)
```

Logo após, executei esse dataset recém criado sendo uma tentativa sem o pandas(trecho comentado):

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open("C:\\Documents\\experimento\\full_dataset.csv",'r') as foutput:   
    '''reader = csv.reader(foutput)
    listaNova = list()
    for r in reader:
        listaNova.append(r)
    print(listaNova)
    '''
    reader = pd.read_csv("C:\\Documents\\experimento\\full_dataset.csv", chunksize=100000)      
    for read in reader:
        print(read)
```

Mas daí obtive:

```py
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

E com o pandas deu esse resultado:

```py
             0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0      0.17730  0.016505  0.058989 -0.314010  0.079795  0.293890  0.035616   
1     -0.68875 -0.340940 -0.647040  0.108130  0.404710 -0.161510 -0.329860   
2      1.27170  0.913990  1.389600  0.834080  0.347450  0.705510  0.547070   
3     -0.53242 -0.566420 -0.558360 -0.813050 -0.365800 -0.352100  0.106440   
4      0.17730  0.016505  0.058989 -0.314010  0.079795  0.293890  0.035616   
..         ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
238  117.00000 -0.532420 -0.566420 -0.558360 -0.813050 -0.365800 -0.352100   
239  118.00000  0.177300  0.016505  0.058989 -0.314010  0.079795  0.293890   
240  119.00000 -0.688750 -0.340940 -0.647040  0.108130  0.404710 -0.161510   
241  120.00000  1.271700  0.913990  1.389600  0.834080  0.347450  0.705510   
242  121.00000 -0.532420 -0.566420 -0.558360 -0.813050 -0.365800 -0.352100   

            7        8         9  ...  46611  46612  46613  46614  46615  \
0    0.390770  0.35301  0.425470  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
1    0.125460 -0.13454 -0.061552  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
2    0.357910  0.85464  0.346880  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
3   -0.545210 -0.64630 -0.519490  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
4    0.390770  0.35301  0.425470  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
..        ...      ...       ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   
238  0.106440 -0.54521 -0.646300  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
239  0.035616  0.39077  0.353010  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
240 -0.329860  0.12546 -0.134540  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
241  0.547070  0.35791  0.854640  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
242  0.106440 -0.54521 -0.646300  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   

     46616  46617  46618  46619  46620  
0      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
1      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
2      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
3      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
4      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
..     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  
238    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
239    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
240    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
241    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
242    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  

[243 rows x 46621 columns]
```

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma em visualizar o dataset inteiro sem eles estarem todos resumidos e na opinião de vocês qual é o melhor método para concatenação e leitura de dataset, se no caso sem o pandas ficaria melhor? Minha intenção é procurar uma forma em trabalhar com esse dataset comparando com os valores pré-convertidos e ler ele dividindo-o por linhas x colunas e padronizar a quantidade de colunas em todas as linhas. Obs: Sou iniciante nessa área de ciência de dados.

Comment: Você precisa realmente disso tudo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você tem um arquivo .csv  quer visualizar o seu conteúdo, a melhor opção é abrir o mesmo numa planilha, como o LibreOffice ou o Excel.

Se o número de linhas supera oque so seu programa de planilha consegue lidar com conforto, então você pode abrir num editor de textos, como o notepad++ ou sublimetext.
Ou pode até mesmo apontar seu navegador diretamente para o arquivo .csv - os dados brutos vão aparecer no navegador.

Há um motivo pelo qual o Pandas resume os dataframes a partir de um certo tamanho:
não tem nenhuma utilidade ver 1000+ linhas de dados brutos, a não ser para ter um "feeling" dos tipos de dados e faixas em que estã distribuidos. E para esse feeling, ou você usa a versão resumida, ou filtra as linhas para encontrar valores interessantes (ordena por uma coluna específica e vê os primeiros valores, etc...).

Ver milhares de linhas de dados serve para ... nada ... .

Agora, isso é configurável no Pandas  -basta configurar a opção:

```
 pd.options.display.max_rows = <numero de linhas desejado>
```

Falei mais sobre isso aqui: [Não consigo listar os valores exclusivos do dataframe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388578/n%c3%a3o-consigo-listar-os-valores-exclusivos-do-dataframe/388643#388643)

E no caso, você só precisa trocar aquele

```
for read in reader:
    print(read)
```

por

```
print(reader)
```